# Não funciona focus no input

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Quando a página está expandida está funcionando perfeitamente, mas no momento que redimensiono para o tamanho de um celular ele quebra da maneira que quero mesmo, mas o *focus* só está funcionando para o último campo.

Usando Bootstrap v3.2.0

O que fiz de errado?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label class="display-label alinhamentoLabel">Razão Social</label>
                    <input type="text" name="razao_social" id="razao_social" placeholder="RAZÃO SOCIAL" required 
                    value="" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label class="display-label alinhamentoLabel">Nome Fantasia</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nome_fantasia" id="nome_fantasia" placeholder="NOME FANTASIA" required 
                    value="" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label class="display-label alinhamentoLabel">CNPJ/CPF</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cnpj_cpf" id="cnpj_cpf" placeholder="CNPJ/CPF" required 
                    value="" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label class="display-label alinhamentoLabel">Inscrição Estadual</label>
                    <input type="text" name="inscricao_estadual"   id="inscricao_estadual" placeholder="INSCRIÇÃO ESTADUAL" 
                    value="" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu, sinceramente, ainda não consegui entender o motivo do problema, mas tirando as classes **col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12** de todas as suas inputs funcionará.

**Editado**

OK, pelo que entendi, você definindo em suas divs que o tamanho será col-md-3, mas não definindo o tamanho para dispositivos com resolução sm ou xs, o Bootstrap acaba se perdendo um pouco. Então se você alterar seu código inserindo col-sm-12 e col-xs-12 juntamente com o col-md-3, funcionará, pois você definirá de fato como quer que fique a disposição dos elementos em resoluções menores.

Ficaria dessa forma:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                    <label class="display-label alinhamentoLabel">Razão Social</label>
                    <input type="text" name="razao_social" id="razao_social" placeholder="RAZÃO SOCIAL" required 
                    value="" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                    <label class="display-label alinhamentoLabel">Nome Fantasia</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nome_fantasia" id="nome_fantasia" placeholder="NOME FANTASIA" required 
                    value="" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                    <label class="display-label alinhamentoLabel">CNPJ/CPF</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cnpj_cpf" id="cnpj_cpf" placeholder="CNPJ/CPF" required 
                    value="" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                    <label class="display-label alinhamentoLabel">Inscrição Estadual</label>
                    <input type="text" name="inscricao_estadual"   id="inscricao_estadual" placeholder="INSCRIÇÃO ESTADUAL" 
                    value="" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado Adriano com isso também resolveria o meu problema, mas a solução que encontrei foi adicionar nas tags <label> as classe "col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" com isso também funcionou..

Comment: Legal, bom saber...

Comment: Alterei meu código para o jeito que você indicou, acredito que seja o correto.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode resolver da seguinte maneira:

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('razao_social').focus()">
```

Comment: O problema é que isso é um formulário e vai ser carregado no celular e quando clico no campo ele não pega o focus para digitar no campo, apenas o ultimo que é o campo "Inscrição Estadual" os outros fica como se estivesse bloqueado.